# Use Dialog to add new row in a table

Tags: sapui5

In my app I have some tables with different cols. 
I want insert new rows by dialogs. My idea is to create a dialog fragment containing a form.
The problem is that the form not have items element where I can define the template of single couple label-input (in Table I can do it)

I would like something like this:

```
<form:SimpleForm
    <items>
       <FormItem>
            <elements>
                <Label text="{label}" />
                <Input text="{value}" />
            </elements>
       </FormListItem>
    </items>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

What is the right way to add new row in a table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this my solution:

This is my init function:

```
onInit: function() {
        //set model
        var oModel=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("model/modelTabCeScd.json", "", false);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        this.getView().bindElement("/elements/");
        //add editable info in case of new row
        var table =this.byId("idDetailsTable");
        var aCols= table.getColumns();
        for(var i = 0; i<aCols.length; i++){
            var bEnabled=oModel.getProperty("/elements/idDetailsTable/cols/"+i+"/enabled/");
            aCols[i].getHeader().enabled=bEnabled;
        }
    }
```

and here i manage the creation of the new dialog

```
onPressAddNewRow: function (oEvent) {
        if (!this.rowTableDialog) {
            this.rowTableDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "ui5bp.view.fragment.RowTableDialog",
                this 
            );
            this.getView().addDependent(this.rowTableDialog);
        }
        var form =this.rowTableDialog.getContent()[0];
        var table =this.byId("idDetailsTable");
        var aCols= table.getColumns();
        form.removeAllContent();
        for(var c = 0; c<aCols.length; c++){
            var oCol=aCols[c];
            form.addContent(new sap.m.Label({text:oCol.getHeader().getProperty("text")}));
            form.addContent(new sap.m.Input({value:"", enabled:oCol.getHeader().enabled, editable:true}));

        }
        this.rowTableDialog.open();
    }
```

This is my Model http://jsbin.com/saqorarafo/1/edit?js

This solution works! But at the end I have listened @Qualiture suggestion and I have created one dialog fragment for each table!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new JSONModel property, which holds a single object containing the fields you want to add and bind that to your dialog. 
Upon submitting your dialog form, add that object to the array of objects (ie. your 'rows')

Comment: ok, but I have different table (with different cols) and in the dialog I have not the same fields (label).

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem? In that case, create a new object which matches the destination fields (columns) of your table and add that object to the JSONModel array

Comment: I understand your solution, but I would like not re-create a new model; I want reuse the same model that i use to bind the table. Do you like my answer? @Qualiture

Comment: Well, I'm not talking about a new model, I'm talking about a new model property. That way you will also have the freedom to reset values -- how would you in your solution handle a 'cancel editing' operation, for instance? You're writing directly into your table model property, so you cannot cancel. And secondly, I don't particularly like creating a form in code (would prefer it in XML) but that's a personal taste

Comment: Ok, but if I don't create my form by code I must create It by XML (one xml for each table).
For example tha table1 have colA colB and table2 have ColF ColG ColH ColK.
If I not create the form by code I must create two XMLdialog with respectively 2 and 4 fields. (`FormItem` not exist. It is a my idea)

Comment: I understand your usecase. I'm not saying it is incorrect, it's just a matter of taste :) And if you only need text input, it will work just fine. However, if you need more freedom (select, radiobuttons, etc) I would use a separate dialog XML for each dialog. From a maintenance point of view, this will also be more easier to read then a UI generated through code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65361/discussion-between-bradipo-and-qualiture).